# Add Print Invoice Button after Payment (On Thank You page)

Tags: invoice, print

Is there a possibility to add a Print Invoice Button on thank-you/success page?  (See example)

I know User can get Invoice if they fill in this form:

https://www.domain.com/sales/guest/form/

Please advise, 
Sandra

[image]